# VBA Atan2 function returns incorrect result

Tags: vba, math, atan2

I was trying to solve a problem over on Math Stackexchange (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4752547/3d-transformation-matrix-to-euler-angles) and I found that my problem seems to be related to VBA's execution of the Atan2 function.
Here's a minimum code example:

Python:

```
print(math.atan2(-0.384, 0.617) * 180 / math.pi)
```

Result:

```
-31.896741982732813
```

VBA:

```
Debug.Print Application.Atan2(-0.384, 0.617) * 180 / Pi
```

Result:

```
121.896741982725
```

I checked without the degrees conversion, and the results were similarly incorrect.

Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: As they sum to 90 degrees is a hint that the parameter order is swapped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These functions have different parameter order (y-x versus x-y).

```
Phthon:
math.atan2(y, x)

VBA:
expression.Atan2 (Arg1, Arg2)  ' Arg1 is The x-coordinate of the point.
```

Please refers to Microsoft document:

> [WorksheetFunction.Atan2 method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.atan2?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

You will get the same answer with:

```
Python:
print(math.atan2(0.617, -0.384) * 180 / math.pi)
```